# How to set the file downloading with Open Browser keyword in the RobotFramework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to set the file downloading without dialog window in the Firefox. I use that code:

```
${Number_value} =  Evaluate  4-2   # I need it to set numeric value not string
${DesiredCapabilities} =  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
Set To Dictionary  ${DesiredCapabilities}  browser.download.downloadDir=${downloadDir}
                ...                     browser.download.folderList=${Number_value}
                  ...                   browser.download.useDownloadDir=${True}
                  ...                   browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone=${True}
                  ...                   browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone=${False}
                  ...                   browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete=${False}
                  ...                   browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting=${False}
                  ...                   browser.download.manager.useWindow=${False}
                  ...                   browser.download.useDownloadDir=${True}
                  ...                   browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force=${False}
Log  ${DesiredCapabilities}
Open Browser  about:blank  firefox  desired_capabilities=${DesiredCapabilities}
```

I see that [Save] button is pushed during the test but the file is not downloading and the dialog window is not hidden.

Log of the ${DesiredCapabilities}:

> {'browserName': 'firefox', 'marionette': True, 'acceptInsecureCerts': True, 'browser.download.downloadDir': ${downloadDir}, 'browser.download.folderList': 2, 'browser.download.useDownloadDir': True, 'browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone': True, 'browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone': False, 'browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete': False, 'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting': False, 'browser.download.manager.useWindow': False, 'browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force': False, 'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'application/sql'}

The geckodriver.log file has such lines:

```
1589738958827   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 52174
1589738958828   Marionette  DEBUG   Marionette is listening
1589738959167   Marionette  DEBUG   Accepted connection 0 from 127.0.0.1:52187
1589738959169   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,1,"WebDriver:NewSession",{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox","capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox"}}}]
1589738959170   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1589738959196   Marionette  TRACE   [18] Frame script loaded
1589738959200   Marionette  TRACE   [18] Frame script registered
1589738959206   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,1,null,{"sessionId":"872cf638-e4ae-465b-a00a-0887601cd3f3","capabilities":{"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"76.0. ... alse,"moz:webdriverClick":true,"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox"}}}}]
1589738959213   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,2,"WebDriver:SetTimeouts",{"script":60000}]
1589738959213   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,2,null,{"value":null}]
1589738959216   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,3,"WebDriver:SetTimeouts",{"implicit":0}]
1589738959217   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,3,null,{"value":null}]
1589738959219   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,4,"WebDriver:Navigate",{"url":"about:blank"}]
1589738959226   Marionette  TRACE   [18] Received DOM event beforeunload for about:blank
1589738959227   Marionette  TRACE   [18] Received DOM event pagehide for about:blank
1589738959233   Marionette  TRACE   [18] Received DOM event DOMContentLoaded for about:blank
1589738961616   Marionette  TRACE   [18] Received DOM event pageshow for about:blank
```

Looks like my custom settings are not used in the test.

How I can set custom settings for the Firefox in the [Open Browser](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser) command?

(robotframework 3.2; robotframework-seleniumlibrary 4.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Changing download setting in Chrome and Firefox are done differently. In case of Firefox you should go with custom Firefox profile and in case of Chrome you should go with capabilities.

Additionally for Firefox you have to specify content types for which download dialog should not be displayed. To find out what content type is returned by server just check response headers:

[image: dev tools screenshot]

Here is python code to setup profile:

```py
# SeleniumExtension.py
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile


class SeleniumExtension:

    @keyword("Set Up Firefox Profile")
    def setup_firefox(self):
        profile = FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)

        # Uncomment to set custom download dir
        # profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/some/valid/path")

        # To make sure that browser won't try open pdf in browser
        profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

        profile.set_preference(
            "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "image/jpeg"\
            "application/octet-stream"
        )

        profile.update_preferences()
        return profile.path
```

Usage:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    SeleniumExtension.py

*** Test Cases ***
Testing-Download
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
    ${profile_dir}    Set Up Firefox Profile
    Open Browser    http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/download    ff    ff_profile_dir=${profile_dir}
    Click Element    //a[contains(@href, ".jpg")]
    Sleep    2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but it doesn't work for me. A file is not downloading. But I'll check your advice to configure the FF profile.